# cannot find -lfl when i compile a file with flex ( Windows)

Tags: c, flexbox, compiler-errors, compilation

i have this code

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}

%%
[0-9]+     printf("Entier : %s\n", yytext);
[a-zA-Z]+  printf("Mot : %s\n", yytext);
\n         printf("Nouvelle ligne\n");
.          printf("Caractère inconnu : %s\n", yytext);
%%

int main() {
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

it's my first code in flex
i work on a windows and i have installed flex with MSYS2

i use this command to compile my flex file in c : flex mon_lex.l

and this gives me this file : lex.yy.c

but when i try to comilate this file with gcc lex.yy.c -o mon_compilateur -lfl

i has this error : cannot find -lfl
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

first of all i try to search by myself and i discover that i didn't have the libfl.a insatlled, so i find a version of it on the web and i try again but the result steel the same

Do you have any solution ?

why and a solution ton my error

Comment: The `fl` library isn't needed on all systems. Try building without it and see what happens.

Comment: without -lfl i have an other error , undefined reference to `yywrap'

Comment: You can define (implement) that function yourself. It and its behavior is well-documented.